# Logstash or Elasticsearch integration with Apache Spark streaming

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-spark, logstash, spark-streaming

Is it possible to receive live input streams of logs from Logstash or Elasticsearch into Spark Streaming?

I see there's a builtin Flume receiver. But any existing Custom receivers for Logstash or Elasticsearch?

Comment: From https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/output-plugins.html, there is no output plugin to spark. but logstash->kafka->spark is possible. you can also write your own plugin. but I am curious, why do not use flume?

Comment: Simple reason really is that I prefer Logstash over Flume

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possibly the best solution currently seems to be to use the logstash output plugin for kafka and then read the kafka topic using spark kafka receiver

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-kafka-integration.html